# Acessar valor do vetor pelo índice

Tags: c, array

Estou praticando um pouco de vetor, ao me deparar com este código, de um exercício:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
  char ex3[5] = { 'z', 'k', 'w', 'x', 'v' };
  int cont1;
  cont1 = 2;
  printf ("%c %c",ex3[cont1+1], ex3[4]+cont1);
}
```

O que entendi:

No trecho, `ex3[cont1 + 1]`  compreendi o seguinte: soma o valor da variável `cont1` ao valor `1`, o que será `ex3[3]` e retornará o  `x`

Entretanto no trecho `ex3[4] + cont1` , não consegui compreendê-lo,  o índice `4` do vetor `ex3` será `v`, mas não entendi o que a variável `cont1` está fazendo ali.

Por que `ex3[4] + cont1`  terá como resultado `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está fazendo ali só quem escreveu o código pode dizer. Pode ter sido sem querer. Se foi por querer o significado seria que ela quer a próxima letra do alfabeto, pulando uma, (tecnicamente o próximo caractere da tabela ASCII estendida) ao que foi pego naquele índice. Então como 4 é o índice que tem um  `v` o próximo caractere, pulando um, é o `x` (estou pulando um porque o `cont1` vale 2, se valesse 1 não precisaria pular um. Não estou falando que pegará o próximo elemento o *array*, isso é feito apenas no `ex3[cont1 + 1]`.

Você está somando 2 ao número que encontra ali.

Eu sempre falo isso, muita gente não entende sobre representação gráfica de um número.

O tipo `char` é um número como outro qualquer em que é garantido ter 1 byte, portanto você pode representar 256 números diferentes. Você pode usar isso como número mesmo, é tranquilo, experimenta imprimir com `%d` em vez de `%c`.

Quando você pega esse dado e manda imprimir com o formatador `%c` em vez de ele colocar um texto com o número que vale ali (na verdade um texto de 1 a 3 caracteres só com dígitos numéricos), ele imprimirá um único caractere baseado em uma tabela ASCII estendida, ou seja, para cada número tem um caractere gráfico correspondente.

Tabela ASCII normal (sem a parte estendida que são os caracteres que vão de 128 à 255):

[image: tabela ASCII]

Alguns caracteres não são exatamente imprimíveis, ou a impressão tem um jeito especial de tratar, e tem o número 0 que é o terminador de texto e não um caractere válido.

Então quando pega o `v` que você vê no seu código, para o computador na verdade é só o número 118. Quando soma 2 ele pega o 120 e na tabela equivale ao `x`.

Faça um experimento: troque as letras dentro do *array* por 5 números. Pegue os números olhando as letras de acordo com a tabela acima. Não fica tão legível, mas para esse fim explica melhor o que está acontecendo.

Você apenas está mandando imprimir o número 120 como um caractere da tabela ASCII. Se mandasse impri9mir só o número imprimiria `120` (três caracteres composto por dígitos numéricos). Se mandasse imprimir como número hexadecimal então imprimiria `78` (novamente dois caracteres) mas isso tudo não muda o número que para nós que estamos acostumados com decimal é o 120. Lá na tabela ainda mostra a forma octal ou como é a entidade do HTML, e poderia ter outras formas de representar um número.

Tem muitas formas de representar números. Estou representando o número 3, todo mundo sabe que é um 3 olhando isto:

[image: 3 patos de borracha]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Na tabela ASCII os caracteres char possuem uma representação Decimal, Hexadecimal, Octal e `char`. 
Vamos focar apenas nas representações decimal e char.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com a tabela, o 'v' é equivalente a 118 em decimal. 
Quando é feita a soma `ex3[4] + cont1`, (em que `ex3[4] = 'v'` e `cont1 = 2`, sendo do tipo `int`) o resultado é equivalente a 120 em decimal.

Como a saída do print está em char `%c`, esse resultado é convertido para o respectivo caractere, que, conforme a tabela, é o 'x'.

Se você fizer:

```
printf("%d", 'a');
```

vai obter 97 como resultado, que é a representação decimal do 'a'. Partindo dessa ideia você pode testar vários exemplos somando `char` com `int`, fazendo a conversão e verificando o resultado na tabela ASCII.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!